# What is the kernel of this localization map?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Let $A$ be an Artinian local ring, and let $R := A[[x,y]]/(xy-a)$, where $a$ is in the maximal ideal of $A$. Let $n$ be such that $a^n = 0, a^{n-1}\ne 0$.

Let $S := \{1,x,x^2,\ldots\}$. Consider the localization map
$$f : R\rightarrow S^{-1}R = A[[x]][\frac{1}{x}]$$
What is the kernel of $f$?

Certainly $f$ sends $y\mapsto a/x$, and so if $i + j \ge n$, then $f(a^iy^j) = 0$. This implies that the kernel contains $(a,y)^n$. Is that the entire kernel?

Comment: If you have some $b \in A$ with $ab = 0$, then $(xy - a)b = xyb \in (xy - a)$, so $yb$ is killed by $x$ in $R$ i.e. $yb$ is in the kernel of the localization. But $yb$ doesn't have to be in $(a, y)^n$ e.g. for $A = k[a,b]/(a,b)^2$